# why is an api call taking too long to respond? calling the same api url through postman gives results instantly

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, api, postman

this is the frontend where i call the api:

```
componentDidMount() {
try {
this.setState({ id: this.props.Id })
await api.get('/match/query/' + this.props.Id).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
this.setState({ users: res.data })
            })
        } catch (Error) {
            console.log("ERROR " + Error);
        };
    }
```

backend for the api call:

```
router.get('/query/:id', async (req, res) => {
try {
const user = await match.findById(req.params.id);
// console.log("this is user from query-------------------", user);
let m = moment(user.date)
        m1 = m.subtract(4, 'h');
        m = moment(user.date)
        m2 = m.add(2, 'hours');
let query = await match.find({ $and: [{ date: { $lte: m2 } }, { date: { $gte: m1 } }, { _id: { $ne: req.params.id } }] });
// console.log("query from query----------------------------", query)
        res.json(query)
    }
catch (err) {
        Console.log(err)
    }
})
```

[the dev options in chrome has nothing returned:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/231ep.png)
[the same page after about 5 mins:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAa9M.png)

Comment: In your first piece of code. Did you have async before `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Also does calling endpoint directly in browser work?

Comment: No i haven't. Is this the reason thats making it take too long? Calling endpoints directly has been working for me in other components. (Different api url, get type)